# My NetWorkDays is sometimes more than the Calendar days

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So in my job, I am trying to find the average calendar days between two dates and average business days.
For calendar days, I am using:

```
=[@[DateLastInReview ]]-[@[DateTimeStamp ]]
```

For Business days, I am using:

```
=NETWORKDAYS([@[DateTimeStamp ]], [@[DateLastInReview ]], Holiday)-(1-MOD([@[DateLastInReview ]]-[@[DateTimeStamp ]],1))
```

They should both give me the dates to a decimal place... but my issues is sometimes the business days are higher than the calendar days. Which makes no sense. Because of how the data is being copied from excel, I had to show the time Stamp separately from date Stamp. But, they are in the same cell when using the NETWORKDAYS equation.

```
+----------------+---------------+-------------------+------------------+--------+--------+
| DateTimeStamp  | DateStampTime | DateLastInReview  | LastInReviewTime | PreCal | PreBus |
+----------------+---------------+-------------------+------------------+--------+--------+
| 2018-07-11     | 12:00 AM      | 7/12/2018         | 12:00 AM         |   1.00 |   1.00 |
| 2018-07-09     | 3:07 PM       | 7/10/2018         | 9:42 AM          |   0.77 |   0.77 |
| 2018-07-02     | 12:34 PM      | 7/3/2018          | 7:45 AM          |   0.80 |   1.80 |
| 2018-07-02     | 3:34 PM       | 7/3/2018          | 8:06 AM          |   0.69 |   1.69 |
| 2018-07-02     | 9:59 AM       | 7/3/2018          | 8:06 AM          |   0.92 |   1.92 |
| 2018-06-29     | 1:54 PM       | 7/2/2018          | 9:52 AM          |   2.83 |   1.83 |
| 2018-07-09     | 11:46 PM      | 7/11/2018         | 9:16 AM          |   1.40 |   2.40 |
| 2018-06-29     | 11:57 AM      | 6/29/2018         | 1:58 PM          |   0.08 |   0.08 |
| 2018-07-05     | 1:29 PM       | 7/6/2018          | 9:08 AM          |   0.82 |   1.82 |
| 2018-07-05     | 3:49 PM       | 7/6/2018          | 10:21 AM         |   0.77 |   1.77 |
| 2018-06-27     | 10:31 AM      | 6/28/2018         | 9:38 AM          |   0.96 |   1.96 |
| 2018-07-06     | 2:46 PM       | 7/9/2018          | 8:58 AM          |   2.76 |   1.76 |
| 2018-06-28     | 3:32 PM       | 7/10/2018         | 7:12 AM          |  11.65 |   7.65 |
| 2018-06-29     | 3:04 PM       | 7/2/2018          | 11:24 AM         |   2.85 |   1.85 |
| 2018-07-11     | 10:28 AM      | 7/11/2018         | 1:25 PM          |   0.12 |   0.12 |
| 2018-07-10     | 3:30 PM       | 7/11/2018         | 2:29 PM          |   0.96 |   1.96 |
| 2018-06-26     | 4:09 PM       | 7/3/2018          | 12:42 PM         |   6.86 |   5.86 |
| 2018-06-28     | 9:18 AM       | 6/28/2018         | 10:58 AM         |   0.07 |   0.07 |
| 2018-07-09     | 11:39 PM      | 7/11/2018         | 9:06 AM          |   1.39 |   2.39 |
| 2018-07-06     | 10:40 AM      | 7/6/2018          | 3:00 PM          |   0.18 |   0.18 |
| 2018-07-02     | 9:33 AM       | 7/2/2018          | 2:12 PM          |   0.19 |   0.19 |
| 2018-07-10     | 12:00 AM      | 7/10/2018         | 4:39 PM          |   0.69 |   0.69 |
| 2018-07-03     | 8:20 AM       | 7/6/2018          | 9:00 AM          |   3.03 |   2.03 |
| 2018-06-27     | 8:52 AM       | 6/29/2018         | 9:07 AM          |   2.01 |   2.01 |
| 2018-07-09     | 12:50 PM      | 7/11/2018         | 8:56 AM          |   1.84 |   2.84 |
| 2018-07-05     | 2:56 PM       | 7/6/2018          | 12:53 PM         |   0.91 |   1.91 |
| 2018-07-10     | 8:43 AM       | 7/10/2018         | 9:42 AM          |   0.04 |   0.04 |
| 2018-07-10     | 8:43 AM       | 7/10/2018         | 9:42 AM          |   0.04 |   0.04 |
+----------------+---------------+-------------------+------------------+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too many parentheses:

```
=NETWORKDAYS([@[ DateTimeStamp]],[@[ DateLastInReview]])-1-MOD([@[ DateTimeStamp]],1)+MOD([@[ DateLastInReview]],1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be the way the NETWORKDAYS function works. `=NETWORKDAYS("7/12/2018","7/13/2018")` evaluates to 2, while `7/13/2018 - 7/12/2018` evaluates to 1.

Comment: I was running into that issues too.. so that is when i went ahead and added the mod function. `=NETWORKDAYS("7/12/2018","7/13/2018")-(1-MOD("7/13/2018"-"7/12/2018",1))` would give 1 day. Same as `7/13/2018 - 7/12/2018`